# SVG animation is not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, html, svg, svg-animate

I am using svg and i wanna animate it using the animate tag as shown in the code below:

```
<svg id="svg_anim" width="100%" height="500" viewBox="0 0 750 160">
    <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0,-892.9134)">
        <g id="g4610" transform="matrix(0.78599195,0,0,0.78599195,25.527464,548.09428)">
            <g id="second_path" class="circle_hover">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="fill_anim2">
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#71D0E8">
                            <animate id="second_arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="first_circle_anim2.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"></animate>
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ded9d5">
                            <animate id="second_arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="first_circle_anim2.end" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"></animate>
                        </stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path style="opacity:1;fill:url(#fill_anim2);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1.32999992;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 266.24609,462.17383 c -36.92375,-3.57967 -65.48691,13.85595 -64.78711,41.50917 0,0 -0.51423,51.85493 -0.50508,74.24685 0.01,23.45457 -27.31442,22.80234 -47.3058,23.13426 1.10753,2.14916 2.88782,5.74543 2.89096,8.18003 -9.6e-4,3.99327 -1.55391,7.81901 -4.31054,10.61914 3.27885,-1.0397 75.01148,3.93253 71.9746,-42.69184 -1.31839,-20.24093 0,-72.46832 0,-72.46832 -0.20538,-18.15802 14.03939,-23.13357 41.84376,-25.10351 -1.71604,-2.50694 -2.64034,-5.50017 -2.64649,-8.57031 0.006,-3.19035 1.00362,-6.29442 2.8457,-8.85547 z" transform="translate(0.5714286,1.42857)" id="path4573"></path>
                <ellipse ry="14.89975" rx="14.426742" cy="472.45868" cx="278.39835" id="ellipse4579" style="opacity:1;fill:#fb787f;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1">
                    <animate id="second_circle_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#ffa98f" to="#0066B3" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </ellipse>
                <text class="head_content" x="250" y="450">Sample
                    <animate id="text_anim3" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </text>
                <text class="head_content" x="235" y="385">SAmple
                    <animate id="text_anim4" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </text>
                <text class="sub_content" x="175" y="405">Sample Text
                    <animate id="text_anim5" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                    <tspan x="225" y="425" class="sub_content">Sample Text
                        <animate id="text_anim6" onend="func_call()" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="second_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                    </tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
            <g id="first_path" class="circle_hover">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="fill_anim1">
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#71D0E8">
                            <animate id="first_arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="1s;text_anim6.end+2s" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"></animate>
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ded9d5">
                            <animate id="first_arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="1s;text_anim6.end+2s" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"></animate>
                        </stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path style="opacity:1;fill:url(#fill_anim1);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 18.929688,529.44141 c 1.140051,2.17164 1.739409,4.60197 1.74414,7.07226 -0.0033,2.41521 -0.575072,4.79339 -1.666016,6.92969 l 36.876954,0 c 17.101683,0 11.124297,14.78094 13.525192,34.92207 7.304679,27.32129 35.935342,38.13518 62.612922,41.73111 -1.5457,-2.42739 -4.33484,-7.94712 -4.33733,-10.8524 0.005,-3.11453 0.90166,-5.74434 2.66254,-8.27277 -23.30774,-1.1068 -29.8766,-7.34118 -39.33413,-22.29658 -4.829034,-11.35821 5.68082,-49.23338 -28.703413,-49.23338 z" transform="translate(0.5714286,1.42857)" id="path4471"></path>
                <ellipse style="opacity:1;fill:#ffa98f;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" id="ellipse4571" cx="142.68405" cy="610.67297" rx="14.426742" ry="14.89975">
                    <animate id="first_circle_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#ffa98f" to="#0066B3" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </ellipse>
                <text class="head_content" x="115" y="650">Q1 2017
                    <animate id="first_text_anim1" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </text>
                <text class="head_content" x="108" y="678">sample
                    <animate id="first_text_anim2" attributeName="fill" from="#F67A83" to="#4F3CAA" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </text>
                <text class="sub_content" x="60" y="700">SAmple TExt
                    <animate id="first_text_anim3" attributeName="fill" from="#0D5982" to="#684F28" begin="first_arrow_fill2.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

MY Js for repeat :

```
function func_call(){
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("svg_anim").setCurrentTime(0);
        }
    },2000);
}
```

This Code works fine in Chrome, firefox but in IE9 it doesn't.

My Question:

Is there any better way to restart the animation from beginning.
Or else can my code work in IE9.

Need Help please. This has been draining my time for few days.

Comment: you want [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for IE - use [Fake Smile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/)

IE9 lacks animation support but supports programmatic animations via scripting.

So, `Fake Smile` can help in this case.

Comment: already included to my html. I works fine for the first time. my problem is it doesn't work on the second time

Answer (score 0):

You're using SMIL (declarative) animation, which is not supported in Internet Explorer. As far as I can tell, Microsoft has no plans to ever support it. From this page,

> "script-based animation opens the door to simple as well as complex
>   animation possibilities. Because of this, and for other reasons (such
>   as CSS animations), IE9 does not support declarative animation."

Microsoft really wants you to use script based animation. So if you want your SVG to animate in all current browsers, you'll need to do it with Javascript. Alternatively, as hinted at by Microsoft, you could use CSS animation. In my opinion, a CSS animation would be the best choice for the simple animation in your example.

You can use the [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) library to add animation support to IE

Comment: already included to my html. I works fine for the first time. my problem is it doesn't work on the second time